# How to find Index of an array in php while loop

Tags: php

I am fetching data from MySQL database... I want to check index of each row...
e.g

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
{
i want index of $row in each row... (current Index).
}
```

Please Help me. 
Thanks

Comment: `$i = 0;` before the loop and `$i++;` in the end of the loop body

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want the index from the database:

```
<?php
...
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM whatever");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['index']; 
   # Where index is the field name containing the item ID from your database
}
...
?>
```

Or, if you want to count the number of items based on the output:

```
<?php
..
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM whatever");
$index = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $index.' '.$row['whatever'];
    $index++;
}
..
?>
```

That's what I understood from your question..

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly you want something like this

```
<?PHP
$i=0;
while($someThingIsTrue) {
   echo $i;
   $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$row is not a member of any array. So, it has no index at all.
And, I suppose, you don't need it either